# What can be said about $f''$ if the trapezoidal approximation is always an overestimate?

Tags: calculus, integration, numerical-methods, approximation

For any $a$ and $b$ the Trapezoidal approximation of the integral $\int_a^b f(x)\,dx$  is an overestimate. What can you conclude about the second derivative of $f$?

---

I think it might mean that the second derivative is increasing, which would cause the original function to be concave up?

Comment: Hint: try drawing a picture when every trapezoidal approximation is too large.

Comment: Hint: Try the graph of $\frac{1}{x}$.

Comment: But I don't know what that says about the function's second derivative... I think it might mean that the second derivative is increasing, which would cause the original function to be concave up....????

Comment: See [math notation guide](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation). I edited the formula in your post. Titles in the form of coherent sentences and moderate use of punctuation are highly recommended, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that means the graph of $y = f(x)$  must be below every secant line connecting the points $(a, f(a))$ and $(b, f(b))$ this is one of the characterization of $f$ being concave up. another one is having $f'' > 0.$

in fact you can drive $$\int_a^b f(x) dx = (b-a)\left(\frac12 f(a) + \frac12 f(b)\right) - \frac1{12}(b-a)^3f''(c) \text{for some  } c, a < c < b.$$